can't see php errors even after changing php.ini settings
I have checked my PHP ini file (php.ini) and display_errors is set and also error reporting is E_ALL. I have restarted my Apache webserver.
I have even put these lines at the top of my script, and it doesn't even catch simple parse errors. For example, I declare variables with a $ and I don't close statements ;. But all my scripts show a blank page on these errors, and I want to actually see the errors in my browser output.
I have even put these lines at the top of my script, and it doesn't even catch simple parse errors:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


Those lines can't catch parse errors because parsing must happen before any code is executed! If the code isn't valid then none of it is executed. Therefore those lines can only help to show runtime errors which occur during execution, not before it

Check that you've modified the correct php.ini file for the web environment,  and then restarted your webserver. Using the phpinfo() command to show all the setting will confirm which php.ini file is relevant, if you're unsure

You should never expose those to the public. Read the error logs.

While Markus is correct, showing errors on-screen in your private development environment is perfectly fine, for debugging purposes. Just never do that in a live environment (which is another reason putting those PHP lines in to show the errors is a bad idea - with that in place you lose the ability to keep your code the same in different environments but configure the error handling differently via the ini file).
